# Solving $x^2 y''-2xy'=0$ using power series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Given the following ODE
$$x^2 y''-2xy'=0$$
I'm trying to solve it using power series. Since
$$y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}x^{n}$$
then
$$x^{2}y''=\sum_{n=2}a_{n}n(n-1)x^{n}$$
and
$$2xy'=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2a_{n}nx^{n}=2a_{1}x+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}2a_{n}nx^{n}$$
Therefore, in the equation, I get
$$-2a_{1}x+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(n^{2}-3n)a_{n}x^{n}=0$$
So
$$-2a_{1}=0\Rightarrow a_{1}=0$$
and
$$(n^{2}-3n)a_{n}=0,\quad\forall n\geq2$$
Since I'm looking for non-trivial solutions, $a_{n} \ne 0\Rightarrow n^{2}-3n=0$ which gives me $n=0$ or $n=3$.

I want to know if it's right and if so, what I'm supposed to do with these values of $n$.

Comment: I corrected this line $a_{n} \ne 0\Rightarrow n^{2}-3n=0$ I guess thats what you meant. And you didn't mean equal $a_n=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an Euler equation, so there's an easier way to solve and one expects two solutions of the form $y=x^r$.  So what you've discovered is that $a_n$ is NOT zero only when $n=0$ or $n=3$.   So you're getting the right answer $a_0 x^0 + a_3 x^3.$

Comment: The equation $n^{2}-3n=0$ came for $n\geq2$. So can I still say that $a_{0}\neq0$?

Comment: Yes.  Since nothing is forcing it to be $0$.

Answer (score 2):

The $n=0$ does not come from the equation:
$$n^2-3n=0 \,\, n \ge 2$$.
This gives you only $n=3$.

The $n=0$ comes from the fact that you have no constraint on $a_0$. So that you have $a_1=0, a_0 \ne 0, \,$  $a_3 \ne 0$. And $a_n=0 $ for $n \ge 2$ and $n \ne 3$.

The solution is therefore:
$$y(x)=a_0x^0+a_3x^3=a_0+a_3x^3$$

Answer (score 1):

Simplify dividing by $x$
$$x y''(x)-2 y'(x)=0$$

set $y'(x)=p(x)$, The equation becomes
$$x p'(x)-2p(x)=0$$
separate variables
$$\frac{dp}{p(x)}=\frac{2dx}{x}$$
integrate both sides
$$\log p(x)=2\log x+C$$
$$p(x)=k_1x^2\to y'(x)=k_1x^2$$
integrate again to get $y(x)$
$$y(x)=k_1\frac{x^3}{3}+k_2$$